# SIP forwarding via DNS. Possible?

Tags: dns, voip, sip, telephony, google-voice

Let's say I have an address `sip:john.doe@example.com` that I would like to use for Internet calls, but my SIP provider is Callcentric and I need to route such calls to `sip:17775551234@callcentric.com`.

Is it possible to setup such proxying or forwarding via DNS? If not, what is the easiest way to do it without a need of own server or client running on my end?

Answer (score 0):

Usually SIP providers allows you to forward only to extension/username on the same domain. So probably you can't forward to other domains. (You can't set a full SIP URI as the forward destination, only the username part)